# Looping elegantly the message SOS in Arduino LED blinks

Tags: while-loop, arduino, morse-code

I am trying to make my Arduino blink "SOS" in Morse Code as my first real programming project ever.

I have succeeded in doing so, however now I would like to more efficiently write the code. Here is the my version. How can a while loop be implemented to get the S blinking twice? That seems to complicate keeping track of iterations with a counter.

```
int led = 13;
//yj Integer representing dit (morse ' . ')
int dit = 500;
//yj Integer representing dah (morse ' - '>)
//yj Testing a multiple of another constant integer to make the timing scalable.
int dah = dit*3;
int blankTime = 100;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait  
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait  
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait

  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dah);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dah);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dah);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait

  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait
}

//TODO:
//Loop counter implementation for multiples (SOS = 3 dit, 3 dah, 3 dit.)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for a simple function to generate morse code instead of writing interation again and again. It coulde something like this.

GenerateMorseCode(char MorseArray[], int len);

You can fill MorseArray with some identifier for dit and dah: May be you can use dot (.) and hipen(-). So for 3 dit , 3dah and 3 dit. Your array would be

```
...---...
```

with length of array as 9. Now inside GenerateMorseCode function all you need to do to parse the MorseArray. You can use simple switch case something like this

```
GenerateMorseCode(char MorseArray[], int len)
{
  for(int i =0i<len;i++)
{
switch(MorseArray[i])
{
  case '.':
  //Your led logic in case of dot
  break;
  case '-':
  //Your led logic in case of dah
  break;

}

}

}
```

Further more you can wrap this function inside another function which keep calling GenerateMorseCode function as per specified loops. To generate MorseArray you can create a map of char array with Morse code. You can keep adding new enum and update corresponding Morsemap. Something like this

```
#define MAX_ELEM 12
enum MorseCode
{
    A_M = 0,
    B_M, 
    C_M,
    SOS_M
};

typedef struct MorseMap
{
    char array[MAX_ELEM];
};

MorseMap mm[3] = {{'.','-','\0'},{'-','.','.','.','\0'},{'-','.','-','.','\0'} };
```

Also there is no need to length now, it can be calculated from char array. To access any Morse code use mm[A_M] or mm[SOS_M]

```
GenerateMorseCode(char arr[])
{
  int len = strlen(arry);
  //Above for loop and switch case case 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll take a look at this later as it seems complicated and I am on my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You want a method to represent "dashes" and a method to represent "dots".
Here is an example using pin #13 on an Uno: http://www.devfactor.net/2014/09/22/arduino-made-easy-output-messages-in-morse-code/

```
/*
Morse SOS
*/

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {

  for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
    dot();
  }
  for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
    dash();
  }
  for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
    dot();
  }
}

void dot()
{
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  delay(250);  
}

void dash()
{
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  delay(250);
}
```

Note that the dash() and dot() methods make repeating much more elegant- and require less code than hard-coding each dash or dot.